# Call function of protocol masquerading as generic superclass/interface?

Tags: clojure

E.g.,

```
(defprotocol P
  (foo [x])
  (bar [x]))


(extend-protocol P

  Superclass ;; a java abstract class
  (foo [x]
    (println "superclass"))

  Subclass ;; a concrete java class implementing the above abstract class
  (foo [x]
    (foo (cast Superclass x))))
```

If calling

```
(foo subclass-instance)
```

I would get a stack overflow obviously, but is there some way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here, i.e., call the same function but masquerade as the generic superclass/interface?

**Update:** A clearer example demonstrating a use case for what I'm asking:

```
(defprotocol P
  (extract-properties-into-map [self]))

(extend-protocol P
  PropertyContainer  ;; abstract class
  (extract-properties-into-map
    [this]
    (into {} (for [[k v] (.getProperties this)] [(keyword k) (read-string v)])))

  Foo
  (extract-properties-into-map
    [this]
    (assoc {:properties (extract-properties-into-map
                          ^PropertyContainer this)} ;; this is where it falls apart
      :foo-type (.getFooType this)
      :foo-permissions (.getPermissions this)
      :foo-whatever (.getWhatever this))))
```

Comment: Are Superclass and Subclass records or Java classes?

Comment: @Jared314 Java classes. I just edited the question to reflect that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `cast` is that it works like a `type assertion`, just throwing an exception if your object does not satisfy the is-a relationship.

```
(defn cast
  "Throws a ClassCastException if x is not a c, else returns x."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  [^Class c x] 
  (. c (cast x)))
```

There is no *new interface* being returned to dispatch in a different function, i.e. you have a stack overflow.

I'm not sure what it means to be extending a protocol for an `Interface`? Since you're providing an implementation I guess you should define a `type` first and extend the protocol on that super-type.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: A slightly better answer based on `delegating-proxy` from https://gist.github.com/michalmarczyk/1715851

```
(defprotocol P
   (foo [x])
   (bar [x]))


(extend-protocol P

  Number ;; a java abstract class
  (foo [x]
      (println "superclass:" x))

  Integer ;; a concrete java class implementing the above abstract class
   (foo [x]
    (foo (delegating-proxy x [Number] []))))
```

Called with

```
(foo (Integer. 1))
=> superclass: 1
```

While it does as the question asked and it now wraps the original `x`.  Depending on the requirements, it might be better to delegate `foo` to a function not included  in the protocol, maybe `superfoo`

```
(defn superfoo [x] { :byte (.byteValue x) })

(defprotocol P
  (foo [x])
  (bar [x]))


(extend-protocol P

  Number ;; a java abstract class
   (foo [x]
     (superfoo x))

  Integer ;; a concrete java class implementing the above abstract class
    (foo [x]
      (merge (superfoo x) { :f (.floatValue x)})))
```

I think the underlying issue is Protocols do not know about class inheritance.   Also, seems like Clojure should have a wait to coerce an object to a type.  Type hints do not work in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, it's definitely the original x that is the problem.